# Highlight a cell in excel using Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I want to highlight a cell using python with this code.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('4.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')        
writer.save()

Num_cols = len (df10.TIME1)
print(Num_cols)
for k in range(0, Num_cols):
    a=0
    if df10["TIME1"][k]!=df10["TIME2"][k]:
        b=str(k)
        a='E'+b
        print(a)
        print(df10["TIME1"][k],df10["TIME2"][k])
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('4.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        df10.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
        worksheet.conditional_format(a, {'type': '2_color_scale'})
        writer.save()
```

But it didn't work with this code.If i use this line

```
worksheet.conditional_format('E3', {'type': '2_color_scale'})
```

instead of this line.E3 is highlighted.

```
worksheet.conditional_format(a, {'type': '2_color_scale'})
```

My cell number is variable. I tried also defining "a" value like this `a="'"+a+"'"` but i get error like that `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Sample data working with your code? [Also please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

The `conditional_format()` method takes a range as input. If you want to apply it to a single cell then duplicate the cell into a range like this:

```
conditional_format('E3:E3', options)
```

However, a better approach is to use a numeric range like this:

```
conditional_format(2, 4, 2, 4, options)
```

See the docs on [conditional_format()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-conditional-format) and [Working with Conditional Formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html#working-with-conditional-formats).

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code slightly and it seems to work now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint (0,9,(5,5)))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('4.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1'] # select sheet here

Num_cols = 5
print(Num_cols)
for k in range(0, Num_cols):
    a=0
    if df[0][k]!=df[1][k]:
        b=str(k+2) # added shift for header
        a='E'+b
        print(a)
        print(df[0][k],df[1][k])
        worksheet.conditional_format(a, {'type': '2_color_scale'})
writer.save()
```

AttributeError may come up if address uses lowercase or as some other format problems.